# There are 20 of the 36 numbers are chosen “success”. Pick 10 numbers from the 36,the probability that all 10 I've chosen will be among the 'success’.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I'm looking at a problem as follows:

In a group of 36 numbers, I know that 20 will be chosen as 'successes'. I pick 10 numbers from the 36 and want to know what the probability that all 10 I've chosen will be among the 'successes'.

I have approached this by using a hypergeometric distribution but I don't think it's correct.

$$\frac{{^{20}C}_{10}  \cdot{^{16}C}_{10}}{{^{36}C}_{20}}$$

As a back of the envelope check I calculated this for 4 choices. ie. 
$$\frac{{^{20}C}_4 \cdot {^{16}C}_{16}}{{^{36}C}_{20}}$$ but this gives me a smaller probability than the pick 10 scenario above, however common sense suggests it should be a larger probability.

Could you point me in the right direction? Am I using the correct approach?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

> but this gives me a smaller probability than the pick 10 scenario above, however common sense suggests it should be a larger probability.

I don't see why you would anticipate that the probability for selecting all sixteen failures and four of the twenty successes, would be more than the probability for selecting some ten of each of them.   There's going to be far fewer microstates.

---

Your approach using Hypergeometric distribution for the count of successes in the sample drawn without bias from a population of known success content is *exactly correct*.

Comment: The reason I assume the probability should be larger is because in the choose 4 scenario, I am only 'choosing' 4 numbers now and so I only need 4 to be among the 20 'successes' which must be more likely than having to choose 10 correct?

I think it's similar to a lottery with 20 numbers drawn, it would be a higher payoff for a 'match 10' than for a 'match 4'?

Comment: @mcoyle Not if the lottery office knew what they were doing.  The distribution is a bell shaped curve; and low numbers are just as unlikely as high numbers, while results nearer the mean are the most likely.

Comment: @mcoyle PS: In a lottery where 6 balls are drawn from 46 and matched to 6 numbers, the mean match count is about *half a ball*, so in *that* case your experience that higher counts payoff more is viable.  However this can not be generalised to drawing and matching larger samples.